# Отрисовка стрелки спидометра в canvas

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, canvas, формулы

Хочу сделать анимацию спидометра с помощью canvas. Но мне необходимо, чтобы стрелка спидометра была треугольной формы и при изменении значения, она показывала на необходимое значение, но ее основание всегда оставалось в центре.
Подскажите какую формулу или алгоритм необходимо применить для этого. Код представлен чуть ниже.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),

        // general settings
        middleX = canvas.width / 2,
        middleY = canvas.height / 2,
        radius = 240,

        counterClockwise = false,

        // ticks settings
        tickWidth = canvas.width / 100,
        // tickColor = "#746845";
        tickOffsetFromArc = canvas.width / 40,

        // Center circle settings
        centerCircleRadius = canvas.width / 20,
        centerCircleColor = "#ccc",
        centerCircleBorderWidth = canvas.width / 100,

        // Arrow settings
        arrowValueIndex = .73,
        arrowColor = "#464646",
        arrowWidth = canvas.width / 50,

        // numbers
        digits = [0, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
        digitsColor = "#0a0a0a",
        digitsFont = "bold 20px Tahoma",
        digitsOffsetFromArc = canvas.width / 15,

        //zones
        zonesCount = digits.length - 1;
    // beginning and ending of our arc. Sets by radius*pi
    let startAngleIndex = .75,
        endAngleIndex = 2.25,
        step = (endAngleIndex - startAngleIndex) / zonesCount;

    /*draw zones*/
    let DrawZones = function () {
        const greyZonesCount = zonesCount / 1.6;
              greenZonesCount = zonesCount - greyZonesCount,
              startAngle = (startAngleIndex - 0.02) * Math.PI,
              endGreyAngle = (startAngleIndex + greyZonesCount * step) * Math.PI,
              endGreenAngle = (endAngleIndex + 0.02) * Math.PI,

              //zones' options
              sectionOptions = [
                  {
                      startAngle: startAngle,
                      endAngle: endGreyAngle,
                      color: "#e7e7e7",
                      zoneLineWidth: 2
                  },
                  {
                      startAngle: endGreyAngle,
                      endAngle: endGreenAngle,
                      color: "#13b74b",
                      zoneLineWidth: 5
                  },
              ];

        this.DrawZone = function (options) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(middleX, middleY, radius, options.startAngle, options.endAngle, counterClockwise);
            ctx.lineWidth = options.zoneLineWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = options.color;
            ctx.lineCap = "round";
            ctx.stroke();
        };

        sectionOptions.forEach(options => this.DrawZone(options));
    };

    /*draw dots*/
    let DrawTicks = function () {
        startAngleIndex = .73,
        endAngleIndex = 2.27,
        step = (endAngleIndex - startAngleIndex) / zonesCount;
        this.DrawTick = function (angle,count) {

            let fromX = middleX + (radius - tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
                fromY = middleY + (radius - tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle),
                toX = middleX + (radius + tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
                toY = middleY + (radius + tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle),

                centerOfDotX=(fromX+toX)/2,
                centerOfDotY=(fromY+toY)/2;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(centerOfDotX,centerOfDotY,6,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            if (count<6){
                switch (count) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        ctx.fillStyle="#F9AF00";
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                ctx.fillStyle="#FFF";
                ctx.strokeStyle="#13B74B";
                ctx.shadowColor = "#a8bbaa";
                ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.shadowBlur =0;
        };
        let count=0;
        for (let i = startAngleIndex; i <= endAngleIndex; i += step) {
            let angle = i * Math.PI;
            count++;
            this.DrawTick(angle,count);
        }
    };

    //draw numbers
    let DrawDigits = function () {
        let angleIndex = startAngleIndex;

        digits.forEach(function (digit) {
            let angle = angleIndex * Math.PI,
                    x = middleX + (radius - digitsOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
                    y = middleY + (radius - digitsOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle);

            angleIndex += step;

            ctx.font = digitsFont;
            ctx.fillStyle = digitsColor;
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            ctx.fillText(digit, x, y);
        });
    };
    /*draw arrow РИСОВАНИЕ СТРЕЛКИ*/
    let DrawArrow = function () {
        let arrowAngle = arrowValueIndex * Math.PI;
        let toX = middleX + (radius) * Math.cos(arrowAngle)+50;
        let toY = middleY + (radius) * Math.sin(arrowAngle)-50;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(middleX, middleY);
        ctx.lineTo(toX, toY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = arrowColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = arrowWidth;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    };


window.onload=()=>{
    DrawZones();
    DrawTicks();
    DrawDigits();
    DrawArrow();
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот еще вариант, старый уничтожать не стал, пусть будет второй ответ:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),

    // general settings
    middleX = canvas.width / 2,
    middleY = canvas.height / 2,
    radius = 240,

    counterClockwise = false,

    // ticks settings
    tickWidth = canvas.width / 100,
    // tickColor = "#746845";
    tickOffsetFromArc = canvas.width / 40,

    // Center circle settings
    centerCircleRadius = canvas.width / 20,
    centerCircleColor = "#ccc",
    centerCircleBorderWidth = canvas.width / 100,

    // Arrow settings
    arrowValueIndex = 0,
    arrowColor = "#464646",
    arrowWidth = canvas.width / 150,

    // numbers
    digits = [0, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    digitsColor = "#0a0a0a",
    digitsFont = "bold 20px Tahoma",
    digitsOffsetFromArc = canvas.width / 15,

    //zones
    zonesCount = digits.length - 1;
// beginning and ending of our arc. Sets by radius*pi
let startAngleIndex = .75,
    endAngleIndex = 2.25,
    step = (endAngleIndex - startAngleIndex) / zonesCount;

/*draw zones*/
let DrawZones = function () {
  const greyZonesCount = zonesCount / 1.6;
    greenZonesCount = zonesCount - greyZonesCount,
    startAngle = (startAngleIndex - 0.02) * Math.PI,
    endGreyAngle = (startAngleIndex + greyZonesCount * step) * Math.PI,
    endGreenAngle = (endAngleIndex + 0.02) * Math.PI,

    //zones' options
    sectionOptions = [{
      startAngle: startAngle,
      endAngle: endGreyAngle,
      color: "#e7e7e7",
      zoneLineWidth: 2
    },{
      startAngle: endGreyAngle,
      endAngle: endGreenAngle,
      color: "#13b74b",
      zoneLineWidth: 5
    }];

  this.DrawZone = function (options) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(middleX, middleY, radius, options.startAngle, options.endAngle, counterClockwise);
    ctx.lineWidth = options.zoneLineWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.color;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  sectionOptions.forEach(options => this.DrawZone(options));
};

/*draw dots*/
let DrawTicks = function () {
  startAngleIndex = .73,
  endAngleIndex = 2.27,
  step = (endAngleIndex - startAngleIndex) / zonesCount;
  this.DrawTick = function (angle,count) {
    let fromX = middleX + (radius - tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
        fromY = middleY + (radius - tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle),
        toX = middleX + (radius + tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
        toY = middleY + (radius + tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle),
        centerOfDotX=(fromX+toX)/2,
        centerOfDotY=(fromY+toY)/2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerOfDotX,centerOfDotY,6,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    if (count<6){
      switch (count) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
          ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
          break;
        default:
          ctx.fillStyle="#F9AF00";
          break;
      }
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle="#FFF";
      ctx.strokeStyle="#13B74B";
      ctx.shadowColor = "#a8bbaa";
      ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.shadowBlur =0;
  };
  let count=0;
  for (let i = startAngleIndex; i <= endAngleIndex; i += step) {
    let angle = i * Math.PI;
    count++;
    this.DrawTick(angle,count);
  }
};

//draw numbers
let DrawDigits = function () {
  let angleIndex = startAngleIndex;
  digits.forEach(function (digit) {
    let angle = angleIndex * Math.PI,
            x = middleX + (radius - digitsOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
            y = middleY + (radius - digitsOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle);
    angleIndex += step;
    ctx.font = digitsFont;
    ctx.fillStyle = digitsColor;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillText(digit, x, y);
  });
};

/*draw arrow РИСОВАНИЕ СТРЕЛКИ*/
let DrawArrow = function () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(middleX-17, middleY-47);
    ctx.lineTo(middleX, middleY-180);
    ctx.lineTo(middleX+17, middleY-47);
    ctx.strokeStyle = arrowColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = arrowWidth;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(middleX, middleY, 50, Math.PI/8- Math.PI/2, 2 * Math.PI-Math.PI/8- Math.PI/2);
    ctx.stroke();
};

function draw() {

   ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   
   DrawZones();
   DrawTicks();
   DrawDigits();
   
   ctx.translate(middleX,middleY);
   ctx.rotate(arrowValueIndex);
   ctx.translate(-middleX,-middleY);
   
   DrawArrow();
 
   ctx.translate(middleX,middleY);
   ctx.rotate(-arrowValueIndex);
   ctx.translate(-middleX,-middleY);
}

window.onload = draw

function val(value) {
  let sector = Math.PI*0.385
  if (value < 40)
    arrowValueIndex = value/40*sector - sector*2;
  else
    arrowValueIndex = (value-40)/60*sector*3 - sector;
  document.querySelector('span').textContent = value;
  draw();
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="60" onmousemove="val(this.value)"><span></span><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо:)

Comment: @Tema4910 да нет вопросов, Вы поняли что никакие формулы не потребовались? хоть можно было и посчитать это все

Comment: как число в range соотносится с числами на спидометре?

Comment: @Grundy никак, я в другом посте написал что с этим проблема, надо циферки другие

Comment: @Grundy можно повыпендриваться и замапить корректно, но я не стал, там сначала шаг по 20 а потом по 10

Comment: надо просто функцию отображения числа на угол поворота

Comment: ну да, один if, сейчас добавлю на самом деле

Answer (score 1):

Печально что распределение шкалы неравномерное, если бы оно было равномерное можно было бы сделать нечто такое

```
function draw() {

   ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height) //очистка канвы

   ctx.translate(middleX,middleY);   // сдвиг в центр
   ctx.rotate(arrowValueIndex);      // поворот табло
   ctx.translate(-middleX,-middleY); // сдвиг обратно

   DrawZones();
   DrawTicks();                      // рисует табло
   DrawDigits();

   ctx.translate(middleX,middleY);   // сдвиг в центр
   ctx.rotate(-arrowValueIndex);     // обратный поворот табло
   ctx.translate(-middleX,-middleY); // сдвиг обратно

   DrawArrow();                      // стрелка

}
```

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),

        // general settings
        middleX = canvas.width / 2,
        middleY = canvas.height / 2,
        radius = 240,

        counterClockwise = false,

        // ticks settings
        tickWidth = canvas.width / 100,
        // tickColor = "#746845";
        tickOffsetFromArc = canvas.width / 40,

        // Center circle settings
        centerCircleRadius = canvas.width / 20,
        centerCircleColor = "#ccc",
        centerCircleBorderWidth = canvas.width / 100,

        // Arrow settings
        arrowValueIndex = 0,
        arrowColor = "#464646",
        arrowWidth = canvas.width / 150,

        // numbers
        digits = [0, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
        digitsColor = "#0a0a0a",
        digitsFont = "bold 20px Tahoma",
        digitsOffsetFromArc = canvas.width / 15,

        //zones
        zonesCount = digits.length - 1;
    // beginning and ending of our arc. Sets by radius*pi
    let startAngleIndex = .75,
        endAngleIndex = 2.25,
        step = (endAngleIndex - startAngleIndex) / zonesCount;

    /*draw zones*/
    let DrawZones = function () {
        const greyZonesCount = zonesCount / 1.6;
              greenZonesCount = zonesCount - greyZonesCount,
              startAngle = (startAngleIndex - 0.02) * Math.PI,
              endGreyAngle = (startAngleIndex + greyZonesCount * step) * Math.PI,
              endGreenAngle = (endAngleIndex + 0.02) * Math.PI,

              //zones' options
              sectionOptions = [
                  {
                      startAngle: startAngle,
                      endAngle: endGreyAngle,
                      color: "#e7e7e7",
                      zoneLineWidth: 2
                  },
                  {
                      startAngle: endGreyAngle,
                      endAngle: endGreenAngle,
                      color: "#13b74b",
                      zoneLineWidth: 5
                  },
              ];

        this.DrawZone = function (options) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(middleX, middleY, radius, options.startAngle, options.endAngle, counterClockwise);
            ctx.lineWidth = options.zoneLineWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = options.color;
            ctx.lineCap = "round";
            ctx.stroke();
        };

        sectionOptions.forEach(options => this.DrawZone(options));
    };

    /*draw dots*/
    let DrawTicks = function () {
        startAngleIndex = .73,
        endAngleIndex = 2.27,
        step = (endAngleIndex - startAngleIndex) / zonesCount;
        this.DrawTick = function (angle,count) {

            let fromX = middleX + (radius - tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
                fromY = middleY + (radius - tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle),
                toX = middleX + (radius + tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
                toY = middleY + (radius + tickOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle),

                centerOfDotX=(fromX+toX)/2,
                centerOfDotY=(fromY+toY)/2;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(centerOfDotX,centerOfDotY,6,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            if (count<6){
                switch (count) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
                        break;
                    default:
                        ctx.fillStyle="#F9AF00";
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                ctx.fillStyle="#FFF";
                ctx.strokeStyle="#13B74B";
                ctx.shadowColor = "#a8bbaa";
                ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.shadowBlur =0;
        };
        let count=0;
        for (let i = startAngleIndex; i <= endAngleIndex; i += step) {
            let angle = i * Math.PI;
            count++;
            this.DrawTick(angle,count);
        }
    };

    //draw numbers
    let DrawDigits = function () {
        let angleIndex = startAngleIndex;

        digits.forEach(function (digit) {
            let angle = angleIndex * Math.PI,
                    x = middleX + (radius - digitsOffsetFromArc) * Math.cos(angle),
                    y = middleY + (radius - digitsOffsetFromArc) * Math.sin(angle);

            angleIndex += step;

            ctx.font = digitsFont;
            ctx.fillStyle = digitsColor;
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            ctx.fillText(digit, x, y);
        });
    };
    /*draw arrow РИСОВАНИЕ СТРЕЛКИ*/
    let DrawArrow = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(middleX-17, middleY-47);
        ctx.lineTo(middleX, middleY-180);
        ctx.lineTo(middleX+17, middleY-47);
        ctx.strokeStyle = arrowColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = arrowWidth;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(middleX, middleY, 50, Math.PI/8- Math.PI/2, 2 * Math.PI-Math.PI/8- Math.PI/2);
        ctx.stroke();
    };

function draw() {

   ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
   
   ctx.translate(middleX,middleY);
   ctx.rotate(arrowValueIndex);
   ctx.translate(-middleX,-middleY);
   
   DrawZones();
   DrawTicks();
   DrawDigits();
   
   ctx.translate(middleX,middleY);
   ctx.rotate(-arrowValueIndex);
   ctx.translate(-middleX,-middleY);
   
   DrawArrow();
   
}

window.onload = draw;

function val(value) {
  let sector = Math.PI*0.385
  if (value < 40)
    arrowValueIndex = value/40*sector - sector*2;
  else
    arrowValueIndex = (value-40)/60*sector*3 - sector;
  document.querySelector('span').textContent = value;
  draw()
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="60" onmousemove="val(this.value)"><span></span><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Интересная реализация:) Спасибо за пример. Но я хочу реализовать стандартный спидометр

Comment: @Tema4910 значит я не понял что Вы хотите, надо стрелку поворачивать?  `но ее положение всегда оставалось в центре` - как тогда это понимать?

Comment: Да, довольно странно я объяснил. Я хотел сказать, что основание стрелки при изменении значения должно оставаться в центре (как на часах)

Comment: @Tema4910 я не понял все равно, можно какой-то пример, ссылка, картинка

Comment: https://sindro.me/t/speedometer/speedometer.html P.S. только стрелка должна быть в виде треугольника (Как видно в примере, основание стрелки всегда находится в центре при изменении значения)

Answer (score 0):

С canvas не работал, но посмотрите данные реализации, возможно помогут:
http://www.knowstack.com/html5-canvas-speedometer/

https://github.com/vjt/canvas-speedometer

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно посмотрю)